# How to send email with bold text

Tags: android, email, gmail

How to send email with **bold** text?

Hi I'm trying send email via android 4.2:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ActionSend);
i.SetType("message/rfc822");
i.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraEmail, new[] { "xxx@gmail.com" });
i.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraSubject, "test email");
i.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraText, "<b>this</b> <b><i>is</i></b> bold");
StartActivity(Intent.CreateChooser(i, "Sending..."));
```

and this:

```
i.SetType("text/html");
i.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraText, Html.FromHtml("<b>this</b> <b><i>is</i></b> bold"));
```

But Gmail income email doesn't have any bold word.

Funny thing: when you must choose android mail, through which to send a letter, the text is displayed with bold letters

Comment: Hi @ssb,serman. I also has this problem, the new gmail app version does not support my bold letters and other html tags. Did you manage somehow the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your sending a plain text email aren't you? thats what it is plain no bold there are other ways to do it like BBCode but the client must support it.

Comment: default gmail client supports bold text. I'm using the wrong tags can be